# Cannot load custom profile python - selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-rc

```
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False);
fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir", self.download_dir);
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/csv");
self.browser = webdriver.Remote("http://192.168.1.242:4444/wd/hub", 
                                     desired_capabilities=webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX,
                                    browser_profile=fp
                                    )
```

the above code does not respect the profile specified.

**BUT** the code below **works** as expected:

```
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
    fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False);
    fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir", self.download_dir);
    fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/csv");
    self.browser = webdriver.Firefox(fp)
```

In the seleniums documentation page http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.html#remotewebdriver
has the following example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
# set something on the profile...
driver = webdriver.Remote(desired_capabilities=webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX,    browser_profile=fp)
```

which is the same as the code in my example.
Also when i start the selenium server with -firefoxProfileTemplate it seems to ignore the profile's settings

```
java -jar ./selenium-server-standalone-2.25.0.jar -firefoxProfileTemplate  /home/xubuntu/.mozilla/firefox/fdui6lsj.crawler/
```

**EDIT:**

I also want to mention that if I load the profile from the file:

```
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('/home/xubuntu/.mozilla/firefox/fdui6lsj.crawler/')

self.browser = webdriver.Remote("http://192.168.1.242:4444/wd/hub", 
                                 desired_capabilities=webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX,
                                browser_profile=fp
                                )
```

the profile is loaded but it takes a lot of time.

Can someone tell me what is wrong?

Comment: please see the question and help. [Question in stackoverflow][1]


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27058053/selenium-python-webdriver-path-error-system-cant-find-the-path-specified

Answer (score 2):

Try calling `update_preferences()` at the end. That should force the writing of the config file:

```
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/csv");
fp.update_preferences()
```